# How to include a query_vars value in document_title_parts?

Tags: pages, title, headers, query-variable

I have a page template, used on a single page, which takes URL string parameters like this...

http://www.example.com/mypage?tags=Publishing

Facilitated like this...

```
// Inherit the meta target
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['tags'])) {
  $tax_meta_key   = 'tags';
  $tax_meta_value = $wp_query->query_vars['tags'];
}
```

It works.

But now I also want to dynamically alter the title of the page based on the same query input.

I have read about several title filter methods. `document_title_parts` suits, since it only changes the title part and leaves the site name and formulation in tact.

However, the following does not work; it just results in a blank title part (not site-name part)...

```
<?php

// Inherit the meta target
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['tags'])) {
  $tax_meta_key   = 'tags';
  $tax_meta_value = $wp_query->query_vars['tags'];
}

// Filter to customise page title from just "Organisation Type"
function custom_title($title_parts) {
    $title_parts['title'] = $tax_meta_value;
    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_title' );

get_header();

?>
```

I suspect this may be down to the order in which a `query_vars` and a `document_title_parts` are executed (?) - ie. Are the vars processed after `get_header`?

Can I include the var in my page title?

Comment: `$tax_meta_value` is undefined from your filter callback. You can do `global $tax_meta_value;`, or better, move the `global $wp_query; if ...` part to the filter callback.

Comment: Or in that callback, you could simply use `get_query_var()` - `$title_parts['title'] = get_query_var( 'tags' )`.

Answer (score 0):

If your query var `tags` is registered properly then the following code snippet will definitely work, I've tested it. It's a modified version of your code snippet. Please make sure to add the code to your `functions.php` file.

```
function prefix_custom_title($title_parts) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['tags'])) {
        $title_parts['title'] = $wp_query->query_vars['tags'];
    }
    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'prefix_custom_title' );
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Though so does the above comment to simply place `global $tax_meta_value;` in the function. The `wp_query` has already been done once, above this function, so maybe best to leave it at that, and use the `$tax_meta_value;` it has already generated?

Comment: I didn't expect that you'd use my given snippet with your one. When you can do things in simple 4 lines inside a function there's no point creating a global variable. Anyway good to hear that you resolved your issue (Y)